# JavaScript REGEX - Identical number 3 times in any order

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to catch any occurance of the same number of a value. Can match the same number (x)times if they are in sequence with

```
((?:1){3}|(?:2){3}|(?:3){3}|(?:4){3}|(?:5){3}|(?:6){3}|(?:7){3}|(?:8){3}|(?:9){3|(?:0){3})
```

But need to also catch if the same number exists 3 times in the entire value. So

```
1110     //true
1123     //false
1121     //true
3212     //false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\d)\d*\1\d*\1
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZ4pC8/2)**

[image]

Update: as **[zzzzBox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497418/zzzzbov)** pointed in this comment

```
(?:(\d)[\s\S]*)(?:\1[\s\S]*){2}
```

..if you want any character between numbers

Comment: I was just about to write this up.

Comment: `/(?:(\d)[\s\S]*)(?:\1[\s\S]*){2}/` if the other characters can be anything, otherwise `'1 1 1'` will fail.

Comment: @fede thanks, worked perfectly. *slunks off to read more about regex.

Comment: @shaundunne glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"1110".match(/1/g).length >= 3`:

```
function number_exists_3_times(input) {
    var result = false, matches;
    for (i = 0; i <= 9 && result === false; i += 1) {
        matches = input.match(new RegExp("" + i, "g"));
        result = (matches !== null && matches.length >= 3);
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(number_exists_3_times("1110")); // true
console.log(number_exists_3_times("1123")); // false
console.log(number_exists_3_times("1121")); // true
console.log(number_exists_3_times("3212")); // false
```